# lp: Unsupported document-format "application/pdf" for Canon LBP6000-LBP6018

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

Before anyone asks, I have already tried the existing solutions and to no avail.

I will however provide full information for debugging.

- lsusb recognizes my printer

  - `Bus 001 Device 023: ID 04a9:271a Canon, Inc. LBP6000`
- Cups also recognizes my printer, when going into the `Printer` options on http://localhost:631/ it the printer is shown. The details are:

  - **LBP6000-LBP6018 (Idle, Accepting Jobs, Not Shared, Server Default)**.
  - **Description**:    LBP6000-LBP6018
  - **Location**:
  - **Driver**: Generic Text-Only Printer (grayscale)
  - **Connection**: usb://Canon/LBP6000/LBP6018?serial=*****
  - **Defaults**:   job-sheets=none, none media=iso_a4_210x297mm sides=one-sided

Doing the lp command gives the error mentioned above.
Inspecting by `tail -f /var/log/cups/error_log` gives:

`Returning IPP client-error-document-format-not-supported for Send-Document (ipp://localhost:631/printers/LBP6000-LBP6018) from localhost.`

Upon checking the `/usr/share/cups/mime/mime.types` file at line 69 the following line is there and not commented

`application/pdf            pdf regex(0,^[\n\r]*%PDF)`

So I do not know why it is happening.

Do I need a specific driver since this printer is old ( maybe 2010,  I do not remember clearly )?

Answer (score 1):

> Driver: Generic Text-Only Printer (grayscale)

There isn't any filter to convert from application/pdf to text. The error_log should show this.

Why choose Generic Text-Only as a driver? Use the drivers that Brother probably provides on its website.